# How to build a funnel for events

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

There is a submission form with multiple URLs, but it has multiple forms on a single URL. Its not a problem to track successful submissions, but I would like to know where they abandon (on which of the forms what are located on a single URL). Is it possible to create a funnel for events to track it and how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

To back up my comment, [the documentation says](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1116091?hl=en&ref_topic=1007030#funnels) explicitly

> When you create a Destination Goal, you also have the option to create
>   Funnel for that Goal.

Since an event goal is not a destination goal there are no funnels for events.

However I don't quite see your problem; you can set different actions or labels with the event for ever form and set up multiple goals, one for each event action (up tp 20 obviously). A funnel would only help you with a multi-step process, I do not see how this applies here.